# Passing SESSION in URL with PHP & Android

Tags: php, android, session, sessionid

we are passing the **session id** in the URL from android to PHP (**Web-service**).Php web-service will get the **session id** & create a session with that ID.

Here we have 2 scenario,

1. Dedicated Server
2. Shared Server

**Dedicated Server** : In dedicated server, session is created successfully with same id & session variables are accessible.(there is no loss)

**Shared Server**: In shared server, session is created but with different Id & session variables are lost.

do i need to configure anything with my shared hosting PHP settings?

**Both Server : PHP Version 5.3.21**

Answer (score 0):

Use an access token. Create it when user log in your application.